# How do you add dynamic partial by concatenating strings in ember js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-cli

We can add partials onto templates in ember js.

```
{{#each subdetail in leftSubDetails}}
   {{partial 'lists/details/link-'+subdetail}}
{{/each}}
```

Gives following error

```
Error: Parse error on line 22:
...lists/details/link-'+subdetail}}
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your use case? It doesn’t make sense to me that you want to dynamically include partials, since there must only be a finite number of known templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the name of the partial as in the view or controller:

```
partialName: function() {
    return 'lists/details/link/ + this.get('subdetail');
}.property('subdetail')
```

Then call it like

```
{{partial partialName}}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a parameter instead, like this:

```
{{partial 'lists/details/link' subdetail=blah}}
```

Comment: Even if you wanted to write a partial with multiple personalities depending on a parameter passed in, unfortunately partials don't take parameters.